# Extra argument 'method' in call of Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift3, parameters, alamofire

I've searched for this issue and there are many answers available but none are solving. I've defined parameters as:

```
let parameters = [
                "name": username,
                "mobile": "",
                "email": email,
                "password": "",
                "blood_donor": "0",
                "registration_id": defaults.string(forKey: "FCMToken"),
                "platform": platform,
                "appID": "3"
            ]
```

And after that when I send the request:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
```

So I get a warning on `parameters`

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any

and if I put `!` next to parameters I start getting this error:

> Extra argument 'method' in call

The function in which I've written all fo this is:
`func sendLoginCall(username: String, email: String, platform: String)`. I have tried replacing `URLEncoding()` to `JSONEncoding.default` it didn't work.

I'm calling this is method like this:

```
if let userName = data["name"], let email = data["email"] {
                            self.sendLoginCall(username: userName as! String, email: email as! String, platform: "fb")
                        }
```

Comment: Can you add the whole `sendLoginCall` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `parameters` type to `[String : Any]` as follow:

```
let parameters = [
                "name": username,
                "mobile": "",
                "email": email,
                "password": "",
                "blood_donor": "0",
                "registration_id": defaults.string(forKey: "FCMToken"),
                "platform": platform,
                "appID": "3"
            ] as [String : Any]
```

Not necessary: Remove `encoding: URLEncoding()` from param arguments, it may work without encoding.

Here is discussion on same issue and resolution by Alamofire developer: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=extra%20argument